# Sorting tailwind classes inside a variable

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I installed a prettier plugin for tailwind which works fine when sorting class names inside `className` attribute. However, it does not sort class names inside a variable like `const className = 'pt-1 p-3'`.

Is there anything I could do to make the sorting possible?

Comment: Why are you creating className variables?  Class names should be close to the jsx element.

Comment: @wuarmin In a Link component with variants, I will have variable like:
`const CLASS_NAME = {
 primary: '...',
 secondary: '...',
}`
The reason I don't want to write this object directly within the `className` attribute is because in my Link component, I either render <Link/> component from react-router or regular <a/> so I will need to write the same object in the attribute of both of them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the plugin is only looking for the `class` and `className` JSX attributes for the string of utility-classes to sort. You can see that here in the plugin code:

```js
function transformJavaScript(ast, { env }) {
  visit(ast, {
    JSXAttribute(node) {
      if (!node.value) {
        return
      }
      if (['class', 'className'].includes(node.name.name)) {

      ...
```

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss/blob/main/src/index.js#L318

Comment: Thanks for looking it up. I might try adding some logic to look up for variables with specific names and send a PR.

Answer (score 0):

**not allowed** to fixed it in a constant ; because it is an attribut standard  of the JSX.
try to restract a class for it and thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's currently a way to do this with the `prettier-plugin-tailwindcss`. However, if you're open to close alternatives, there's the vscode plugin [Headwind](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=heybourn.headwind).

Unfortunately, Headwind only runs on save or keybind (it's not integrated into the Prettier process for CI/CD, automation), and you must be using vscode for development. But if that fits your use case, you can use regexes to customize where in your source code Headwind runs. Instructions are [here](https://github.com/heybourn/headwind#headwindclassregex).